# Create a materialized view with buffer zone from point layer

Tags: postgis, sql-view

I would like to create a process on PostGIS where users can create a point on a working layer ("working_point_layer") close to a reference point layer ("ref_point_layer").

As I can't set the intersection process between 2 points layer, I would like to create a buffer zone on a materialized view.

How is it possible to create a materialized view which will be a spatial layer with this operation `ST_Buffer (ref_point_layer.geometry, 10)`?

(Like that after, I can set a process where user have to create their points on the "working_point_layer" only inside this buffer).

I would like to create a materialized view because if we have to move a point on "ref_point_layer", the buffer zone has to change.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you want...you effectively want to restrict users to create points that are within a distance of the `ref_points_layer` geometries? creating a materialized view with that operation is trivial: `CREATE MATERIALZED VIEW ref_point_layer AS (SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry, 10) AS geometry FROM ref_point_layer);` (if `10` is supposed to be *meter*, make sure your CRS is a metric projection or you are using the *geography* type). but if restricting on DB level is your goal, a trigger might be better suited here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try (provided your table is called `somepoint`, geometry column `geom`):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.myview AS SELECT *, ST_Buffer(geom, 10) AS buffered_geom FROM public.somepoints
```

Note that the resulting view in this case has two geometry columns (because of `SELECT *...`) and that you have to (manually or by trigger) refesh a materialized view by e.g.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.myview
```

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I needed! Just one precision: is it possible to plan to refresh this Materialized view? I presume it is by a trigger?